# Team City V8, changing from checkout as agent to checkout as server, changes working directory

Tags: teamcity-8.0

We are currently using teamcity v8 (eventually will upgrade)
Right now we have a server and agent on the same machine and all the VCS's are set as "checkout as agent".

By doing that I get this directory structure:

```
[agentdirectory]\work\[hashcode]\[all the code]
```

I then tried adding a second agent and needed to change the checkout style to "as server", but then this change happened

```
[agentdirectory]\work\[hashcode]\[branch name]\[all the code]
```

This messes up any build, as I expect the root project.proj file to be directly under [all the code], but now it isn't anymore.

Is there a way to prevent this?  Was this a bug with V8 of teamcity?

This would otherwise force me to change the build folder, testing folders, and artifacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is it’s a bug in the surround scan plugin. They are now aware of it and will fix it “in the future”